NVChad nvim null-ls - failed to run generator
MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1
When I edit a python file I get the below error:

[null-ls] failed to run generator: ...y/null-ls.nvim/lua/null-ls/helpers/generator_factory.lua:220: error in generator output: p
yenv: mypy: command not found


The `mypy' command exists in these Python versions:
3.12.2/envs/pupdb-3.12.2
pupdb-3.12.2

in my proj dir, I have a .python-version with

pupdb-3.12.2

pyenv versions shows:
  system
  2.7.18
  3.8.16
  3.8.16/envs/dcm-3.8.16
  3.12.2
  3.12.2/envs/pupdb-3.12.2
  dcm-3.8.16 --> /Users/nunya/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/envs/dcm-3.8.16
* pupdb-3.12.2 --> /Users/nunya/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/pupdb-3.12.2

How do I troubleshoot, fix this?
